# Firebase: Why $firebaseSimpleLogin throws a SecurityError?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebasesimplelogin

I'm trying to register users using the Firebase Simple Login mechanism:

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseSimpleLogin, FIREBASE_ROOT) {
  $scope.loginService = $firebaseSimpleLogin(new Firebase(FIREBASE_ROOT));
  $scope.user = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
  };

  $scope.register = function() {
    console.log('creating user...'); // I see this
    $scope.loginService.$createUser($scope.email, $scope.password).then(function(user) {
      console.log('done!'); // But not this
      console.log(user);
    });
  };
});
```

But, I see the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin 
"https://s-dal5-nss-15.firebaseio.com" from accessing a frame with origin
"http://localhost:8100".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", 
the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
```

and, the `$createUser` callback is not executed.

I enabled the "Email & Password" authentication and put `localhost` in the list of the Authorized Request Origins.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hey how you solved this problem? i am facing too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, your "domain" (localhost in this case) is `http` whereas the origin is `https`, which tends to cause these sorts of errors. I believe if they match up (however, in this case, both MUST be HTTPS), this should no longer be an issue:

> The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https",  the frame
>   being accessed has a protocol of "http". ***Protocols must match.***

Some more info can be found on the [REST API Reference | Firebase Documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html):

> **Note that HTTPS is required. Firebase only responds to encrypted traffic** so that your data remains safe.