# Access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http"

Tags: http, firebase, firebase-hosting

Has anyone see the following error before??? If so, please provide some advice.
" Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://project-1283108821180873675.firebaseapp.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost:9000".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match."

Thank you,

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to access a file from `http://localhost` in an app that you published. That will not work for two reasons:

1. visitors to `https://project-1283108821180873675.firebaseapp.com` won't have access to your machine (which is what `localhost` refers to)
2. you're trying to load the nested page over `http`, while the main site is loaded over `https`. That is a common phishing technique, so disallowed by all modern browsers.

Replace the iframe `src` attribute with a relative URL (removing the `http://localhost:9000` part).

See [Firebase: Why $firebaseSimpleLogin throws a SecurityError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431924/firebase-why-firebasesimplelogin-throws-a-securityerror)